# Python3 Requests "Post" Ignoring Filename when using BytesIO?

Tags: python, post, python-requests, bytesio

I've written a simple script to expand my skills with python - however I've noticed something very strange when using BytesIO.

Here's my working script:

```
import requests

url = "http://MY.FAKE.IP.ADDR/Uploader.php"
file = open("test.jpg","rb")
action = {"file" : file, "name" : "test.jpg"}
requests.post(url, files=action)
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with an image in the memory (for example, a screenshot), the webserver gets a blank filename?? Here's my code for this:

```
import requests
from PIL import ImageGrab
from io import BytesIO

url = "http://MY.FAKE.IP.ADDR/phUploader.php"

file_name = "test.jpg"

im = ImageGrab.grab()
output = BytesIO()
im.save(output, "JPEG")

file = output.getvalue()

action ={"file":file,"name":file_name}

requests.post(url,files=action)
```

What the file looks like on the webserver:

[image]

However the file once renamed - does contain my image as intended. I can't find anything on this, it's really confusing why this script doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're constructing your requests `files` argument wrong, check the [official documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) on how to construct it.

In your case: `action = {"file": (file_name, file)}` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, I'll read up on it. I learned from a source I suppose that taught me wrong.

Comment: @PieroBird - always check the official documentation before you resort to external sources, including SO - the assumption being that the developers of the module should know the best how to use it.

Comment: Understood, I'll be sure to do that in the future.